# Number of generating elements in a finite cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ is finite cyclic group of order  $37$. Then the number of elements in the set  $\{g\in G\mid \langle g\rangle=G\}$  is equal to?

Is it that easy to say that it is 36? Or there is a theory behind it?

Comment: The answer is, “yes, there is theory behind it” and “the theory gives you the easy answer you have.”

Comment: But the answer is 36 or 37?

Comment: Because I think that if e has to be included they become 36+1=37 elements. Am I correct?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the function you may want to look up is Euler-Totient function?

Comment: You are not mistaken but why this function does the job??

Comment: So if you think about it, $G$ is cyclic then it must have a generator, say $h$, if $h^k \in G$ can generate the same group then it must be the case that $k$ and the order of $G$ are coprime. Then the number of $k's$ that can do this job is precisely the Euler's function. it may even be helpful to consider the most familiar cyclic group like $\mathbb{Z}/37\mathbb{Z}$ and have a little try yourself!

Comment: Well I still do not get it but thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 5):

In a cyclic group of order $n$, the number of elements which generate the group is given by $\phi(n)$, where $\phi$ denotes the Euler's phi function.

Given any $n$, $\phi(n)$ provides the number of primes to $n$.

Let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_n^{\alpha_n}$ be the prime factorization of $n$, $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n$ are distinct primes and $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n\in \mathbb{N}$; then

$\phi(n)=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_n^{\alpha_n}(1-\frac{1}{p_1})(1-\frac{1}{p_2})\dots (1-\frac{1}{p_n})$.

For your example:

$\phi(37)=37(1-\frac{1}{37})=36.$

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin, for pointing this out.